# What is the replacement of SetThreadPriority and GetThreadPriority for windows RT (Metro Style)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, microsoft-metro

I am porting a windows desktop app to metro style app.

My desktop app uses the following system API functions:

**SetThreadPriority**

**GetThreadPriority**

Both the functions are declared in processthreadsapi.h for windows desktop app.These functions  are not compatible for metro style app.

Is there any replacement of these functions for metro style app?

Comment: Do you want to set the priority only with respect to the other threads in the program or with respect to all threads in the system? (this question is not as stupid as it sounds)

Comment: And why do you need to set the priority anyway? IMO it's a very overrated concept.

Comment: @Tudor - certainly GetThreadPriority() - why wouldn't you know?  Setting thread priority lower for long-running CPU-intensive apps is quite useful - 'normal' apps, like Office, browser etc. can run almost normally with their normal priority while the CPU-app soaks up all the remaining CPU.

Comment: @Martin James: AFAIK all modern OSes favor user interactive apps. Assuming office does not use much CPU if left idle (even without a decreased priority), it will anyway preempt a CPU-intensive app when the user focuses the window.

Comment: You'd better take a step back.  CreateThread is not permitted either.

Comment: 'CreateThread is not permitted either' - WHAT??

Comment: @Tudor - idle, empty Excel.exe has 13 threads. Winnword.exe has 6.

Comment: @HansPassant - how are we supposed to do stuff?  What have M$ done?

Comment: @MartinJames: You're supposed to use Microsoft's components. If there is no component, you're writing the wrong Metro program. All applications that you might want to write are about posting on Facebook and Twitter anyway, and there's components for that. No threads and no programming knowledge necessary. Any other applications (like, Office), Microsoft will keep the exclusive monopoly over. You're a dinosaur and you're about to die out (no kidding, that's the plan...).

Comment: @Martin James: You can use the `ThreadPool` though.

Comment: @Damon - thanks a bunch for that reassuring info.  I feel a lot better now that I can look forward to the 'Cretaceous' part of my life, writing Twitter/Facebook scripts - fulfillment at last! <g>

Comment: @Hans Passant, i used _beginthreadex under process.h to create a thread